# Sum of digits of a number keeping certain numbers with Python

Tags: python-2.7, digit

Sorry for my bad english

1) I've found the code to sum digits of a number. I use it in a python algorithm and it works fine !

2)I also found how to obtain a base 9 result
`def sum(n):
    sum_ = n % 9
    return sum_ if sum_ != 0 else 9`

3) But I don't know how to make exceptions : for instance keeping certain numbers (11 or 22 or the number 10, yes I know, it is not a master number) from the first operation (without reducting/digiting them).
It must be very simple but I'm an absolute beginner!

Thanks for your answers

Can someone can help me?

Comment: can you explain your question. may be give us sample input and output for your desired function.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try an be a bit clearer when typing out the question, and fix any typos?

Use `if` statements for exceptions.

```
if n == 10 or n == 11 or n == 22:
    return n
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're asking for but it sounds like it could be the basics you'd find on beginner tutorials.